# SQL JOIN return only the first match

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I think this is a basic question, but I couldn’t figure it out. I am new to this so please bear with me.

I am analyzing players data from the FIFA game, and I want to get a table with the highest rating of each individual player and the earliest age when that happened.

This is an example of the data:

| id | name | position | rating | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | RW | 70 | 20 |
| 1 | James | RW | 71 | 21 |
| 2 | Frank | CB | 73 | 23 |
| 2 | Frank | CB | 73 | 24 |
| 3 | Miles | CM | 75 | 27 |
| 3 | Miles | CM | 74 | 28 |

This is what the query should return:

| id | name | position | rating | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | RW | 71 | 21 |
| 2 | Frank | CB | 73 | 23 |
| 3 | Miles | CM | 75 | 27 |

I thought I could first get the highest overall for each player, and then do a `JOIN` to get the age, but that gives the other years a player had the same highest rating.

| id | name | position | rating | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | RW | 71 | 21 |
| 2 | Frank | CB | 73 | 23 |
| 2 | Frank | CB | 73 | 24 |
| 3 | Miles | CM | 75 | 27 |

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (could be a bit faster):

```
with mytable as (
    select 1 as id, "James" as name, "RW" as position, 70 as rating,  20 as age union all 
    select 1, "James", "RW", 71, 21 union all
    select 2, "Frank", "CB", 73, 23 union all
    select 2, "Frank", "CB", 73, 24 union all
    select 3, "Miles", "CM", 75, 27 union all
    select 3, "Miles", "CM", 74, 28
)
select array_agg(t order by rating desc, age asc limit 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
from mytable as t
group by t.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One approach uses `ROW_NUMBER` with `QUALIFY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE true
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rating DESC, age) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too if you want. I think it's what you need.

```
select p1.id,
       p1.name,
       p1.pos,
       max(p1.rating),
       p1.age
  from players p1
  join (select name, min(age) min_age
          from players 
         group by 1) p2 on p1.name = p2.name and p1.age = p2.min_age
 group by p1.id, p1.name, p1.pos, p1.age
```

Comment: It gives me error from the JOIN  ;  
Error: Unrecognized name: p2   ;  
From this part of the JOIN on p1.id = p2.id

Comment: oh my bad, i edited the code, test please.

Comment: I see now what you did. I tried that too but gives the wrong output when the highest rating is not in the first year the data shows up (like in James case).
For James it shows max_rating = 70, age = 20, when it should be 71, 21.
In any case, thank you for your input.

Comment: I see, it's because i join the p1.id = p2.id, lemme edit again :D just to solve the mystery :D

Comment: I don't think we can do this with JOINs.
The issue is when the highest rating is not on the first year the player appears.
In the subquery iyou are getting the youngest age the player shows up in the table, not the youngest age when the player had the highest rating. This answer would be correct if the player could have multiple ratings with the same age, which it can't.
Thanks for helping me anyway, if one day I figure out  how to make it work with JOINs I will let you know.